# Manually Reload Rails classes that have been 'cached' by enabling cache_classes = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, caching

I'm trying to speed up my web fronted by caching classes in development,

```
My::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
end
```

but I would like to manually reload classes using guard if a file in my model or lib changes.

So the question is this: without restarting my local server, how can i manually trigger a class cache refresh?

**Update**

You can use `reload!`

don't know why i didn't think of that sooner

Comment: I think `reload!` only reloads a model from the database. You're looking to reload your code on each server request. The answer by @apneadiving links to a gem that is already incorporated into Rails 3.2 so it should work automatically. I'm looking into that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I don't answer your raw question, [this link](https://github.com/paneq/active_reload) should answer your goal as a whole.

In a nutshell:

> Reload Rails code in development mode only when change is detected

Comment: nice that such a basic iterative dev productivity rqmt is a gem